# OS: Memory allocation

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, operating-system, allocation

Picture of Problem :
[image]

Given the problem above I have a few questions. First, proc0 takes the place of a hole that is bigger than it, what happens to the remaining space?

For example in Q1 i: after bringing in Proc0 it's `a.   10->15->15->25->30`. Having the 15 replace the 20, theres 5 left, so what happens to it, and how would I depict what happens to it? Would it be a.  10->5->15->15->25->30 or a. 10->15->5->15->25->30?

Comment: This is not notation used outside academia so it is not clear to me what the question is here.

Comment: This is a question about some specific memory allocation algorithm (that seems to care which processor a request comes from) that we know nothing about. So how could we answer? (Or does "Proc" stand for something other than processor? Process? How should we know?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - It is a typical OS problem, which doesn't need any processor to answer; it is a theoretical question which assumes ideal situations.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Does "Proc" here stand for "process"? Or "processor"? If the former, are we talking about allocation of physical memory? That doesn't use holes and sizes but pages -- you don't assign part of a page to one process. If the latter, it *does* depend on the processor (or why are they telling us which processor is issuing the requests).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - From what I believe, proc should go for process. No, we are talking about memory allocation of the process(hole is just a concept used to describe fragmentation, possibly). I think the question is asking about this, and I have added an answer assuming the same.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful So do you have any idea what "after bringing in Proc0" means?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - "after bringing in Proc0" means --- *After request goes to memory manager, requesting for blocks of memory, the management is performed there using these algorithms*. I'd suggest you to visit my answer to understand the whole scenario/

Answer (score 1):

Given, sizes of the `proc`

sz(proc 0) -> 15
sz(proc 1) -> 5

From what I am able to understand, the change in the `Free List (10 -> 20 -> 15 -> 25 -> 30)` is described below :

> Q1 : First Fit (The size of the free-list would start decreasing)

```
When proc 0 (size=15) is brought to the list, 
Free List converts to (10 -> 5 -> 15 -> 25 -> 30)
// the freelist size would decrease wherever the first biggest hole is found,
// so, hole of size 20 is replaced by a hole of size 5 to allocate memory to proc 0

When proc 1 (size=5) is brought to the list, 
Free List converts to (5 -> 5 -> 15 -> 25 -> 30)
// the freelist size would decrease wherever the first biggest hole is found,
// so, hole of size 10 is replaced by a hole of size 5 to allocate memory to proc 1
```

Assuming the FreeList is again the same`(10 -> 20 -> 15 -> 25 -> 30)` before performing the First Fit allocation :

> Q2 : Next Fit (The size of the free-list would start decreasing)

```
When proc 0 (size=15) is brought to the list, 
Free List converts to (10 -> 5 -> 15 -> 25 -> 30)
// the freelist size would decrease wherever the next biggest hole is found,
// so, hole of size 20 is replaced by a hole of size 5 to allocate memory to proc 0

When proc 1 (size=5) is brought to the list, 
Free List converts to (10 -> 0 -> 15 -> 25 -> 30), or better
Free List converts to (10 -> 15 -> 25 -> 30)    // the size of the freelist decreases.
// the freelist size would decrease wherever the next biggest hole is found,
// so, hole of size 5 is replaced by a hole of size 0
// (or, rather no hole left, so list becomes continuous) to allocate memory to proc 1
```